# Angular cli doesn't start new project

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying a lot but with the command ng new appname , my project is not initialising....everything is installed fine but the project still not initiated

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Yes , it says directory is under version control , skip git initialization